# rails - devise keeps returning html responses to ajax requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I've been trying to get devise to return json to ajax requests, but it keeps sending back html instead. I followed [this](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/) (and other, I literally looked at every link on 2 google search pages) tutorial(s) but it still sends html. Here's what I changed and where:

> config/initializers/devise.rb:

added: `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false`

> created app/controllers/sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
end
```

> created app.controllers/registrations_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  
  respond_to :json
end
```

> added under config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  sessions: 'sessions', 
  registrations: 'registrations'
}
```

and I think that's it. but I keep getting html back. Should I delete the partial views associated with devise?

Here's what a request looks like:

> Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-06-17 09:01:19 -0400
>   Processing by SessionsController#create as */*
>     Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "authenticity_token"=>"HDlnoiGZXXoarFjdlfxZL6AF0EY8Xf1K5mRwceVmVw647lG+NPJxDYstXLhiH4BGGwmNrrX8U5gZD8B3IfhS+w=="}

Comment: Can you post your server log of a request coming in?

Comment: @Ruslan I added a request example

Comment: Don't you miss `format: :json` when making a POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `dataType` property on the ajax request, after setting it to `application/json' it worked.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/users/sign_in",
    dataType: 'application/json', <--- here
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfTokenContent
    },
    data: {
      user: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
      authenticity_token: csrfTokenContent
    }
  })
```